# How to attach file to a email through online URL in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am using asp.net web forms. i have an file save on on line server. i want to send that file in attachment. i have URL of the file how i attach the file through URL as attachment in email. please guide me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to download it before attaching. Try something like this...

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUrl);

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var message = new MailMessage("from@email.com", "to@email.com", "subject", "body");
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(responseStream, "myfile.pdf"));
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
}
```